# Manipular json com ajax e utilizar seu dados separadamente

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

PHP:

```
if (@mysql_num_rows($resultados) > 0){
      while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) 
          $retorno = array($linha);           
         // print_r(json_encode($retorno));
          echo json_encode($retorno);
}
```

Como manipular, ou seja, quebrar este json com ajax para que se possa utilizar seus dados separadamente?

A função está assim:
Foi assim que tentei, mais não deu certo... Olha só como fiz:

```
function marcacao(){       
   $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: $server+"/conecta.php",
            data: "acao=marcacao",
            success: function(data) {
                var resultado = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(resultado);  
            for(var i = 0; i<=data.length; i++){
                $Jlati = resultado.employees[1];
                $Jlng = resultado.employees[2];

                var map = new google.maps.Map(
                        document.getElementById("map"), 
                        { 
                          center : new google.maps.LatLng($Jlati[i], $Jlng[i]), 
                          zoom : 5, 
                          mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
                        }
                );


                var image = 'www/images/ray001.png';

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
                    {
                            title : "VOCÊ ESTÁ AQUI: "+$Jlati[i]+", "+$Jlng[i],
                            position : new google.maps.LatLng($Jlati[i], $Jlng[i]),
                            map: map,
                            icon: image
                     });

                marker.setMap(map);  

              }
            }

        });

    }
    marcacao();
```

Porém, nada acontece...

Answer (score 2):

Sem ter os dados certos do seu Json fica difícil construir um código para o seu caso específico, então vou colocar um exemplo de como pode utilizar um Json e aí você adapta para o seu caso, ok?

Nele temos um Json dentro de uma variável, fazemos um parse dele para dentro de um objeto, pegamos um objeto HTML e colocamos o valor do objeto gerado a partir do Json no HTML.

```js
var text = '{"employees":[' +
'{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },' +
'{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },' +
'{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }]}';

obj = JSON.parse(text);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
obj.employees[1].firstName + " " + obj.employees[1].lastName;
```

```html
<p id="demo">O valor do Json entra aqui.</p>
```

No modelo acima o valor apresentado é Anna Smith e é definido aqui: `obj.employees[1]`

Mande executar o código que você verá o resultado. Esse código veio desse [link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_json_parse), nele você pode alterar o código e ver o resultado.